# Having trouble starting hadoop single-node cluster in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, hadoop

When I try to start Hadoop cluster in Ubuntu from the shell I get the following error:

```
    hduser@duleep-G31M-S2L:/usr/local/hadoop$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09': not a valid identifier
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09': not a valid identifier
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09': not a valid identifier
jobtracker running as process 8066. Stop it first.
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-duleep-G31M-S2L.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09': not a valid identifier
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

Please help if you know what's wrong.

Comment: This is a shell problem, nothing to do with Ubuntu or Java. Please paste the appropriate exerpts from hadoop-env.sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the contents of your `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh` script, for the JAVA_HOME export line - looks like you have a trailing quote in there.

For reference, this is what a version i have looks like:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07-i586
```

If you're still having problems, paste your entry back into your original question

Comment: I try with /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09 as my java path but still have same problem.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the above line from your hadoop-env.sh

Answer (score 0):

The java implementation to use.

change this

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0
```

to

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0
```